# Derivative Function Exercise

Tags: derivatives

If $f(x)=g(x)\cdot(x-1)^2$ then I need to find a $g(x)$ such that there will not be a second derivative of $f$ for $x=1$. I don't know what to search for.

Comment: There are loads of options, depending on what you want $g$ to be. An easy option is to have a jump discontinuity at $x = 1$, but there are also options to make $g$ continuous, or even differentiable.

Comment: If it looks complicated just change the problem to $f(x) = g(x) x^2$ where you're considering the point $x=0$ (then you can visualize the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Consider $g(x)=\operatorname{sgn} (x-1)$

Comment: If I choose this g(x), then won't f(x)=|x-1|*(x-1)?

Comment: @M.Papapetros And consequently left side and right side derivatives have different signs.

Comment: You mean so for the limit as x approaches 1 of (abs(x-1))/(x-1), right?

Comment: @M.Papapetros The one side derivatives will be $\pm2$.

Comment: That is what I found as well. Thank you very much for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you come up with such a function $f$?

Note that $f(1)$ has to vanish, if the equation between $f$ and $g$ has to hold for all $x$.

Then $g(x)=f(x)/(x-1)^2$ for $x \ne 1$.

The last thing to do is probably a good choice for $g(1)$.